# Microsoft Graph Teams APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to make use of the [List JoinedTeams API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams).

I have created an application on the [Azure App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), using an enterprise account, and have granted the User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All App permissions, as specified in the documentation.

As the documentation specifies, granting Application permissions allows you to use the GET /users/{id}/joinedTeams API call, which I am using.

So, I'm retrieving the current user ID, and then using the above API call to retrieve the teams of the user.

Unfortunately, it is giving me the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "xxxxxx-xxxx",
        "date": "2018-08-22T07:39:01"
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine on the Graph explorer, but that takes delegated permissions into consideration. Can this be achieved only using Application permissions, and if so, where else do I have to grant these permissions from, if already provided through the App registration Portal?

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Some questions from our dev team: 

1. If there is a request ID / tenant ID, that will be great.
2. Can you confirm that the token you are sending to Graph actually has the right claim (that is, what you expect)?
3. How is the "current user" Id being retrieved here? Through graph explorer?
4. One additional question, was the app re-consented by tenant admin after adding scopes?

Comment: 1. I am unable to share this at the moment. 2. Yes, the token is corrrect. 3. Current user ID is retrieved using "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/" this API call and retrieving the ID. 4. I don't understand this question.

Comment: Also, @BillBliss-MSFT, this application is present on the Azure Active Directory. Are there any additional permissions to be granted there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListJoinedTeams was work specify /me, but did't work specify /user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576589/listjoinedteams-was-work-specify-me-but-didt-work-specify-user)