# ListJoinedTeams was work specify /me, but did't work specify /user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried `ListJoinedTeams` with a specified user, but it didn't work.
I tried `ListJoinedTeams` with myself and `Listmessage` with a specified user and it worked.

- **Doesn't work**

  - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/joinedTeams
- **Works**

  - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/messages
  - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams

Would you tell me how to set users?
I tried it from Graph Explorer.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0](http://[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0][1])

Comment: This seems like a bug. Other Graph endpoints work fine if the user's email address is specified as the {id} parameter, and this one should, too.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Graph only supports `/me` with `/joinedteams` when using Delegated permissions. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions):

> With user delegated permissions this operation only works for the 'me'
>   user. With application permissions, it works for all users by
>   specifying the specific user id. ('me' alias is not supported with
>   application permissions)

Comment: I am able to use the `/users/{userId}/joinedteams` endpoint **with** delegated permissions using an admin account.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for application permissions. Granted both User.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All. Works fine for current user, doesn't for other users.
`Invalid UserId. UserId does not match Access token UserObjectId`